# Merge git repo with fork of its own, but keep both versions of all moved/renamed files

Tags: git, merge, branch

We have two repos, `A` and `B`. `B` is a fork of `A`.

`A` looks like this:

```
my-project
  src
    folder_a
      file1.html
      file2.html
  config.properties
```

`B` looks like this:

```
src
  folder_a
    file1.js
    file2.js
  deploy.yml
```

Notice:

- Repo `A`: All files and folders have been moved into a directory `my-project`.
- Repo `B`: File `config.properties` is missing.
- Repo `B`: All `html`-Files have been converted to `js`-Files.
- Repo `B`: File `deploy.yml` is newly created.

Now I want to merge repository `B` back into Repository `A` (as a matter of fact I'm merging `A` and `B` into a new repository `C`, but I dont see how this would make any difference). But of course git has to handle the conflict of `file1.*`: It was moved AND renamed/modified.
I'd like the file-history of the files to be somehow splitted. Is this even possible?

What we want:

```
my-project
  src
    folder_a
      file1.html
      file2.html
  config.properties
src
  folder_a
    file1.js
    file2.js
  deploy.yml
```

We are open to suggestions how to resolve this situation. We do need the history of both files. Simply copying the files of repository `B` into Repository `A` is not an option :(

Answer (score 0):

Cherrypick the commits from Repo B into Repo A and resolve the conflicts as per your need.

You can add another remote in local repo and then cherry pick else run following command

```
git --git-dir=/<other_repo>/.git format-patch -k -1 --stdout <commit> | git am -3 -k
```

Comment: But wouldn't that destroy our history?

Comment: files history will still be there which you can see by git log --follow ./path/to/file

Comment: We will give it a try

Comment: you can also look - https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/   the example listed seems similar to your case

Comment: sadly, we were not able to preserve the history. Having thought twice about git, this makes a lot of sense: file1.html and file1.js are the same file - there was never a copy operation, just moving & renaming. We had to drop the filehistory in ordner to merge the repositories.

Comment: @samjaf correct, however git provide the way to add/update tree history manually, https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch